# Why can't I put a line between point and errorbar in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, errorbar

I'm trying to add simple error bars with the ggplot function `geom_errobar()`, as I found the code on the web.

[image: Pic of the plot that I get]

The function works, but I don't know why it doesen't put the line between points and bars.

In all examples releted to the explanation of the codes that I found online, there are always a line between points and bars and I used the same code!!!

Short dataset

```
structure(list(Daytime = structure(c(17683, 17684, 17685, 17686, 
17687, 17688, 17689, 17690, 17691, 17692, 17693, 17694, 17695, 
17696, 17697, 17698, 17699, 17700, 17701, 17702, 17703, 17704, 
17705, 17706, 17707, 17708, 17709, 17710, 17711, 17712), class = "Date"), 
    mz33_flux = c(0.0269902340425532, -0.0186273777777778, -0.0372041666666667, 
    -0.065895625, -0.0371895833333333, -0.0685152173913043, 0.0733608695652174, 
    -0.0462857446808511, 0.03306875, -0.0309327083333333, 0.0240914893617021, 
    0.0355631578947368, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1.32546206896552, 
    0.039425, -0.00267916666666666, -0.0299131111111111, -0.207063829787234, 
    0.0057391304347826, -0.0350862790697674, -0.0324617021276596, 
    -0.0234354838709677, -0.0835595744680851, 0.0966265957446808, 
    -0.0124054545454545), mz33_err = c(3.90466069268418e-05, 
    3.94858430704017e-05, 4.24302022766031e-05, 4.46591337717942e-05, 
    6.21204244886397e-05, 4.10959733730185e-05, 5.64638070309499e-05, 
    6.44166726780267e-05, 3.82000202086123e-05, 4.15227904947797e-05, 
    3.8179357878616e-05, 3.09029031996929e-05, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, 0.00102801852277132, 3.86575696937507e-05, 2.93166992687375e-05, 
    3.24126251499621e-05, 5.68095205509716e-05, 7.24229986669278e-05, 
    5.91711611807517e-05, 7.34947840597977e-05, 6.30692813002305e-05, 
    5.4382594393826e-05, 9.84397824539971e-05, 3.30427039605518e-05
    )), row.names = c(NA, 30L), class = "data.frame")
```

ggplot script

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=Daytime))+
  geom_line(aes(y=mz33_flux,colour="y"), size = 1)+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=mz33_flux-mz33_err, ymax=mz33_flux+mz33_err), width=1,position=position_dodge(0.05),color="green")
```

I expect to have connection lines between point and errorbars, as I see in the example plot of the function.

Comment: What are `df` and `dfy`? Is `dfy` a column in the dataframe, or a separate dataframe?

Comment: df=generic dataframe
dfy= my "y" column in the dataframe
I reported a generic code, to avoid to report my specific code with my data.

Answer (score 1):

I think that everything is working fine, but you've a very small error, so you have not connection between points and errorbars; if you multiply your error by 1000, you'll have what you're searching for (clearly the data are different):

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=Daytime,y=mz33_flux,colour="y"), size = 1)+
  geom_line()+
  geom_point() +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=mz33_flux-mz33_err*1000, ymax=mz33_flux+mz33_err*1000), 
                width=1,
                position=position_dodge(0.05),
                color="green")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response.
I didn't provide data, because are little bit complex and I thought that the part of the code with a fake generic reference to data could be enough.

Anyway, I know geomsmoot and geomribbon, but I prefer errobars in this case.
Why they doesen't appear in the normal right way in my plot?
In all the plots showed in the examples of the code (that I simply copied in my plot script) they appears whit the bars connect to points whit lines!

Comment: Sorry, it's the first time that I post an issue on Stackoverflow and I didn't understand very well.
Can I import a subset of my data directly from R or do I have to create a fake dataset similar to mine?

Comment: No worry, I am also here to learn everytime! You can send this command on R : `dput(head(insert here the name of the dataset,20))` and you'll have an output like `structure...`: if you post it *editing the question*, you'll share the first 20 rows of your data, and your code will work, becoming your question with minimal reproducible example. Also, you mentioned  "...In all the plots showed in the examples of the code (that I simply copied in my plot script)..." but there are not those example here: you can share them (links, etc.) to help us to find the issues.

Comment: Thanks.
You are very kind, thanks for your help.
I've done as you suggested me, I hope in the right way.
I've modified my post with a subset of the datasat.

Comment: I see, you need the bars between errors and dots, not bars that links bars from different points: if it's that, look at the edited answer.

Comment: Ok.
So the problem is the magnitude of the error and his visualization!
Bad story.

Thanks anyway
Antonio